# How to open pgAdmin 4 v6.0 in browser instead of running as a desktop app

Tags: pgadmin-4, macos

It looks like PgAdmin 4 v5.4+ (I have v6) works as a standalone desktop app and the option to open in a browser window is not there by default.

I am using macOS Big Sur. How can I open PgAdmin UI in browser?